# change name of downloaded file using while using urlllib

Tags: python

I am currently using the following code to download some csv files:

```
import urllib

year = 2006
max_year = 2019
host = "http://data.wa.aemo.com.au/datafiles/outages/outages-"
ending = ".csv"

while year <= max_year:
    url = host + str(year)+ending
    print(url)
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, url.lstrip(host))
    print("Done")
    year +=1
```

The script works fine however it downloads the files with very generic names just like:

```
2006
2007
2008
...
```

Which can be quite confusing. Ideally I would like the script to download the files like:

```
outages-2006
outages-2007
outages-2008
...
```

How can I modify my code to achieve my desired result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you don't know "lstrip"

click here, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lstrip.htm

use this code instead of "url.lstrip(host)"

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

year = 2006
max_year = 2019
host = "http://data.wa.aemo.com.au/datafiles/outages/outages-"
ending = ".csv"

while year <= max_year:
    url = host + str(year) + ending
    print(url)
    file_name = "outages-" + str(year) + ending
    print(file_name)
    urlretrieve(url, file_name)
    print("Done")
    year += 1
```